# Create new Mapset with Python

Tags: qgis, python, pyqt, subprocess

I've tried to create a new Mapset/Location with Python for hours but I can't figure out how it works.

The problem is that I can't use GRASS.SCRIPT because it already needs an existing Mapset and Location when I want to set it up.

So I tried to use the Shell via the Subprocess Library.

```
import subprocess

gisbase = os.environ['GISBASE']
cmd = gisbase + "/bin/g.mapset.exe -c mapset=testmapset location=testlocation"

p = Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

It runs fine but I don't get any output nor a location or a mapset. Nothing.

Do you have any ideas how I could make it work?

Comment: you can also set up your Mapset with the GUI